Getting "dev/failsafe/Policy" error while using Selenium with java,tried with giving failsafe using maven and via import also but the issue is same
i am using selenium with java and passing the jar via POM.xml file for a simple code to open google page.But getting this error when try to run the script -
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.(ClientConfig.java:33)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:83)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:51)
at Automation_Revision/test.First_test.main(First_test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
... 4 more
selenium version - 4.21.0
java - JavaSE 21
Could anyone suggest how it can be fixed

This question is similar to: When executing selenium code getting failsafe issue. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
